# how i can write 2 characters in the same case line in c language?

Tags: c

I mean i want to add a character next to c in order to enter c or C .

```
  switch (x)
  {
      case ('c') : 

             printf("Donnez vous le cote du carre:");
             scanf("%f",&cote);
             printf("La surface du carre est %f",cote*cote);

             break;
```

Comment: `case 'c': case 'C':`

Comment: fallthrough to the next `case` ... `case 'c': case 'C': doCstuff(); break; case 'd': case 'D': doDstuff(); break;`

Comment: You cannot.  The case statement requires a single criteria.   GCC does have an extension that allow for case-range that allows more than one, but it is not part of the standard yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. Note that any statements *between* the two case statements will be executed for a lower case 'c' but not for uppercase. Also note that the parentheses are unnecessary. The expression `'c'` evaluates to the value of the character constant, which is what you want to compare to the value of `x`, whether or not the parentheses are present.

```
  case 'c' : 
         // fall through
  case 'C' : 

         printf("Donnez vous le cote du carre:");
         scanf("%f",&cote);
         printf("La surface du carre est %f",cote*cote);

         break;
```

Comment: This would be a good opportunity to point out that the parens are unnecessary.

Comment: The parens are not just unnecessary, they are distracting.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Did I capture what needed to be said?